# jquery highlight fading - timeout problem

Tags: jquery, settimeout, jquery-animate

I have two sets of boxex on a page. 10 boxes belonging to class 'boxOne'
and another 10 belonging to class 'boxTwo'
There is a button. On click of button I am using jquery effect to highlight and then fade the background color of all the element belonging to class 'Boxone' and 'Boxtwo'.

Below is the code.

```
var colorOfBox1 = "'" + $(.boxOne).css('backgroundColor') + "'";  
$(.boxOne).animate(
    { 'backgroundColor': "#FF9900" }, 
    { 'queue': false, 'duration': 1000 });

setTimeout( function(){  
        $(.boxOne).animate(
          { 'backgroundColor': colorOfBox1}, 
        {'queue': false, 'duration': 2000} 
      );
}, 2000);

var colorOfBox2 = "'" + $(".boxTwo).css("backgroundColor") + "'";  
$('.boxTwo').animate({ 'backgroundColor': "#FF9900" }, {'queue': false, 'duration': 1000});  
  setTimeout(
    function(){
        $('.boxTwo).animate(  
            { 'backgroundColor': colorOfBox2 }, 
                {'queue': false, 'duration': 2000} 
          );
}, 2000);
```

All the boxes are highlighted with the specified color on click of the button..   Now the problem is that sometimes few out of these boxes don't fade out. Their background remains highlighted. This happens sometimes with no consistency.
I want a consistent behavior.

I see that the setTimeOut() function is not applied uniformly to all the elements belonging to that class...   It is apllied only to few elments..
What fault am i making ?

Comment: I've tested it with about 40 boxes (both boxOne and boxTwo types) and it works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera 10 and IE8

Comment: Thanks for the support.
I am testing on FF. 
Out of 10 clicks about two times it happens that certain boxes are not fading out.
But they fade out if i resize the window.
What is happening..?

Comment: In what way are the results inconsistent?
Does it work differently, even when the number of boxes is the same?
Or when the number of boxes changes?
Or when your run it in different browsers?

Comment: This thing is independent of browser and when i say inconsistent result i mean that few boxes don't go back to their previous backgroud color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i am using this plugin and it just works fine.

http://jquery.offput.ca/highlightFade/old.php

Comment: thank you very much, i was going nuts with the existing libraries, i tried scriptaculous , jquery color library and effects library. ALL of them had some kind of issues. The one you posted works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check the syntax of the Javascript code first. Inconsistent syntax causes inconsistent results on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a few quote marks around .boxOne and .boxTwo in some places. Not sure if that was a formatting error or intentional. Could be causeing issues with some browsers.